Connecting to remote local network devices when connected through VPN on Windows
I have the following setup:

On my Windows 11 computer on my home network, I VPN into my work's network
Once the VPN is connected, I SSH/VNC into an Ubuntu computer
The Ubuntu computer is connected to the work network through a router
The Ubuntu computer has another network card that is configured with a static IP address that is on the same subnet (192.168.1.x) as a bunch of networked devices.
I have a utility that only runs on Windows that I need to connect to one of the locally networked devices described in (4).

Is there a way to configure my Windows 11 PC, the remote Ubuntu computer, and/or its router such that my Windows 11 PC can see the locally subnet'ed hardware devices? I have control over all devices (my Windows PC, the Ubuntu computer, and the router it is connected to).
